# Why my question has been closed?

Tags: discussion, questions

I really don't understand why.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20520082/how-to-make-a-dns-query-using-c-sharp

Comment: It was an extremely vague question. People closed it because you were essentially just asking for code.

Comment: @JoshC, I was asking for explanation of ways to make a DNS request, actually.

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: You can edit it to improve: the title should state GetHostAddresses only returns one address. Then in your question body make Dns.GetHostAddresses a code block with an actual value in it and the response you get, so that I (and others) can try that in one copy-paste action in say LinqPad. Currently it looks like your asking for reimplementation of dig or nslookup. And we might need some more context on your dns setup.

Comment: `the title should state GetHostAddresses only returns one address` - why? `Currently it looks like your asking for reimplementation of dig or nslookup.` - that would solve the task, indeed. Why asking for this is bad?

Comment: Because no-effort questions asking for code are considered bad.

Comment: It is bad to ask for someone to re-implement nslookup because that is a ridiculous thing to ask someone else to toil through. It is beyond the scope of a single answer.

Comment: @Pëkka, it's not no-effort.

Comment: It *reads* like it's no-effort, yet you've clearly tried things.  You need to *demonstrate* the effort you've put in to the problem.  Including working example code is a great start.

Comment: @Travis J, an existing implementation would be fine. An explanation of a DNS request/response format would solve the task as well.

Comment: @Charles, `It reads like it's no-effort` and `yet you've clearly tried things` are mutually exclusive statements.

Comment: @user160319 it should state that in the title because that is the problem  to solve. dns is perfectly speced in this [RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt) but I see no attempt and no need to have an implentation for that.

Comment: How about "from your comments, clearly you've made efforts."  Stop nitpicking our comments and go fix your question before the Meta Effect(tm) downvotes it into oblivion.

Comment: @Charles that was my line!

Comment: @rene, the problem to solve is making DNS request. Everything is described somewhere in specs, and if you are closing every question that might be solved by digging specs for a week - you have to close all StackExchange, because it's not necessary.

Comment: You came asking for feedback, why not listen to it? It's free and given with helpful intent. What else do you expect: "Wow, great question, let me upvote and reopen"?

Comment: This is not my area of expertise, but when I Google `c# dns query`, I see several interesting results. Are they all unsuitable? They may well be, but I find it hard to imagine no one else has had this problem previously

Comment: e.g. [DNS lookup from custom DNS server in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8227863)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What's missing from your question is *context*.  Folks don't want you to show what you've tried because of some idealistic need to know that you're putting effort in. Instead, context helps folks understand the specifics about your problem so that they can more quickly get you an answer that also solves your problem.

Vague questions are really depressing to answer, especially when the question asker comes back with "no! I alredy tried that! It wont work because im doing x".

Essentially, if we know more about all of the things that you tried, we're less likely to answer with things you've already tried. In short, think of it this way; you're helping the answerers help you more effectively.

Lastly, asking questions that are detailed are your way of giving back as an asker. The clearer your question, the more helpful it will be to all of the future visitors from Google with the same problem.

So go ahead and edit your post. Add in more details. Show some code. This will help people know where to start so you can get a solid answer. Once improved, folks who come by to see your post once it's bumped back to the top of the active page may very well vote to reopen. Good luck!

Comment: Some folks are even eager enough to downvote a few unrelated questions of mine. Is this considered normal?

Answer (score 6):

[As jmort notes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211196/why-my-question-has-been-closed/211198#211198), you're lacking context. Specifically, you're describing a situation in which what you're already doing *should* work. There are multiple sources - on MSDN *and* on Stack Overflow - that attest to this.

So... There are a couple of possibilities:

1. There's something unusual about your situation that makes the normal method of solving this problem not work.
2. You're doing it wrong.

But... You don't include any information about your situation OR what you're doing that would allow an answerer to determine which of these things is the case. One might wish to *assume* that you're already well aware of the canonical documentation and other questions on Stack Overflow regarding this topic, and have thus ruled out #2, but that can be a dangerous assumption... And it still leaves #1 conspicuous by its absence.

Now, folks could *guess* at it; throw out ideas for you to try and report back. That might even be what has to happen anyway, if this is such an unusual occurrence that no one's ever encountered it before or in a position to reproduce it. But it'd be nice to avoid that if possible, and yet you've constructed a situation where that's all but *guaranteed* to happen!

So... Try it again. This time, include as much information about

1. Your specific situation (the DNS entry, anything special about how it's configured, why it's configured that way, etc.)
2. The code you're using to query the entry. Not your entire program; just the call to `GetHostAddresses()` and whatever setup goes along with it.
3. The *complete* results that are returned from that call.
4. Anything else you've done to try and debug this.